# How to sort stacked bars in Tableau?

Tags: sorting, tableau-api, stacked-chart

I'm working on simple [stacked bars chart](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/windows/en-us/help.htm#viewparts_marks_stacking_ex1stacking.html%3FTocPath%3DBuilding%2520Data%2520Views%7CParts%2520of%2520the%2520View%7CMarks%7CStacking%2520Marks%7C_____1) in Tableau (8.3), and I want to sort columns according to total value of each column.

This is chart that I've build. Each column represents one artist and size of each column represents followers count across different channels.

[image: Artist followers across different channels]

### Some more info about my data and configuration

- In columns shelf - Artist as `Dimension`
- In rows shelf - `MAX(Follower count)` as `Continuous` `Measure`
- For marks I use "spider" field - value represents channel for which measurement was taken.
- Data comes from two data sources. One is Artists (column Artist) and second is table of measurements where follower count and spider data is stored.

### tl;dr

Basically I want chart to be sorted by `Follower count`, how can I achive that?

Thanks for your comments and effort!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem so that I've added "pid" field from measurements source to columns shelf. I've then hidden that field from visualisation and I was able to sort columns based on `Follower count`. Yey!

[image: Columns sorted by Follower count]

Answer (score 0):

Create another variable that is the sum of follower count: and then sort your artists by that variable. to sort, just click on the pill in the shelf, from the menu select "sort by".

Answer (score 0):

To sort as per your requirement, follow image and apply on your example as :[image]